# Animation in tabular

Tags: tables, animate

When I put an animation (animate package) inside a tabular, I get some weird errors. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\animategraphics{12}{Anim/debut}{1}{22}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives me an Incomplete \ifx error.

On the other hand, the animation outside the tabular and the empty tabular work fine.

What puzzles me even more is that this MWE compiles without any issue on my linux running TeX Live 2009/Debian and my Windows Seven laptop running some old version of MikTeX. This error only occurs on my Windows 8, MikTeX 2.9, pdflatex 1.40.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs in newer animate versions. To be fixed in the next version. As a workaround, try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
{\animategraphics{12}{Anim/debut}{1}{22}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just uploaded the fixed version `[2014/07/02]` to CTAN. With TeXLive-2014 it should be available tomorrow, while with MiKTeX-2.9 it may take one week.