# Conflict between animate package and math delimiters?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, animate

I've encountered an unusual problem with the `animate` package and the use of math delimiters, like `\left\{`.

When compiling the MWE, I get the error `Missing delimiter (. inserted).` on the math line.

But: if I change the order -- putting the math line before `animategraphics` line -- it compiles with no problem.

Is there a known conflict between `animategraphics` and the later use of delimiters? Any thoughts about how to overcome this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\animategraphics[scale=0.5]{6}{animfile}{}{}
\[\left\{\begin{array}{l}y=2x\\y=x+1\end{array}\right.\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As of version `2014/08/06` of `animate`, the problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in `animate`. The macro `\@anim@@sanitize` is executed several times, one for each token in the list `.:;?!/"'*+,->=<$&@][)(^_`|~`, and each time it does

```
\global\let\@anim@leftbrace=\{\global\let\{=\@anim@lbr
```

The first time, `\@anim@leftbrace` saves the meaning of `\{`, but the second time it just saves the meaning of `\@anim@lbr`. Later, `\@anim@endsanitize` does `\global\let\{=\@anim@leftbrace`, restoring the wrong value.

The same happens for `\\`, `\}` and `\%`.

You can cure the bug by doing the loop in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{animate}

\makeatletter
\def\@anim@@sanitize#1\@nil{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname @anim@\number\expandafter`\next\endcsname{%
      \the\catcode\expandafter`\next
    }%
    \global\catcode\expandafter`\next=12
  }
  \global\catcode`\#=12
  \global\let\@anim@newline=\\\global\let\\=\@anim@bksl
  \global\let\@anim@leftbrace=\{\global\let\{=\@anim@lbr
  \global\let\@anim@rightbrace=\}\global\let\}=\@anim@rbr
  \global\let\@anim@percent=\%\global\let\%=\@anim@per
}
\def\@anim@@endsanitize#1\@nil{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \global\catcode\expandafter`\next=\csname @anim@\number\expandafter`\next\endcsname
  }
  \global\let\%=\@anim@percent%
  \global\let\}=\@anim@rightbrace%
  \global\let\{=\@anim@leftbrace%
  \global\let\\=\@anim@newline%
  \global\catcode`\#=6%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\animategraphics[scale=0.5]{6}{whatever}{}{}

\[\left\{\begin{array}{l}y=2x\\y=x+1\end{array}\right.\]

\end{document}
```

This should be brought to the attention of the package maintainer as soon as possible.

### UPDATE

As of version `2014/08/06` of `animate`, the problem has been fixed along with the other bug noted in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much, @egreg. I will try to incorporate this asap.

Comment: I found another way for fixing it. I moved the lines with `\global\let` from the recursive macros `\@anim@@sanitize` and `\@anim@@endsanitize` to the ends of the calling macros `\@anim@sanitize` and `\@anim@endsanitize`.

Comment: @AlexG I don't understand why you want to use your own baked recursive call, when LaTeX provides `\@tfor`. But the package is yours. `;-)`

Comment: I just find recursive macro calls cool. Though without really mastering them ;).

Comment: @AlexG I'd also point out that globally redefining ``\\`` is not really the best thing to do; if `\animategraphics` is called in a `flushleft` or `center` environment, one will end up with ``\\`` having the wrong definition when the environment ends. Do you really need `\global`?

Comment: Recently, I had to group the code bodies of `\@anim@sanitize` and `\@anim@endsanitize` to cure a problem that occurred when `\animategraphics` is called in a `tabular` environment due to the `&` which also figures among the tokens to be treated. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187588 .

Comment: @AlexG That's exactly what I had in mind: try ``\show\\`` before and after a `tabular` containing `\animategraphics` and you'll see the problem. This is a serious bug, in my opinion.

Comment: I found a way to remove the global redefinitions, by grouping the call to the recursive macro only. Next version soon to appear on CTAN. Thank you again for sorting out the bug!

Comment: Maybe setting catcodes globally isn't a good idea too. I will try to remove the need for this.

Answer (score 2):

use instead of `\{` the macro `\lbrace`:

```
\[ \left\lbrace ....
```

Comment: What about ``\\``? Sorry, but this just cures one of the symptoms.